# mysql writing syn solution when my app is scaled to multiple servers

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, synchronization

I have an application (`Spring boot`+`MySql`) deployed at three servers, which work together to perform calculation and then write result to a mysql server. These three servers are behind a single nginx server.

For each arrival request, the processing sequence is shown below. 
[image: Work flow sequence in each app server]

Each server retrieves data from mysql and then writes back calculation result back the record after time-consuming processing. As the retrieved `record` in servers might be the same instance in MySql, the later arrival request in `server2` would finish processing eariler and update the record first, which conflict with what is doing in the `server1`.

So, **my question is What a normal solution to keep mysql write ordered to resolve this write conflict**?  Especially when the server configurations are varied. 
Thanks

Comment: Use [Transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-transaction-model.html) (switch to InnoDB if you are not using it already). Employ [Locking Reads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) using `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` during **Read record from MySQL** part.

Comment: Thanks @MadhurBhaiya . I will research it..